# React Native project in Xcode archives successfully, but doesn't generate an .xcarchive file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

1. Product -> Archive returns success with no warnings
2. In my archive scheme, I have "Reveal Archive in Organizer" checked
3. I have "Skip Install" set to "NO" in deployments in the build settings

When I archive my project, it runs successfully but no where in my system can the .xcarchive file be found. I checked Xcode's default archive folder under Preference -> Locations, but there was nothing there.

Any advice?